# Is the usage of 'x times' correct, if you want x pieces of something?

Tags: numbers

In German you can say something like 'I want this 2 times', meaning that you want 2 pieces of something. Is this correct in English to say, or is the equivalent rather 'I want 2 of these'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(German here, so I know the original.)

No, you should not say "I want this two times".
It is simply not idiomatic in the sense it is used in German, a word-by-word translation doesn't work here.

You *can* say

> I want this *done (or other verb)* two times / twice.

For items, you should stick to the simple

> I want two (of these).

---

Note that you might also want to consider using expressions like

> I'd like to...

instead of "want" - like in German, the politer phrase would be one avoiding a blunt "ich will".